# MultiAutoCompleteTextView modify data before adding to textview

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

lets say I have MutliAutoCompliteTextView with predefinded "Call: " text inside. When I enter contact name and suggestion will pop up, I want to add (for example) html tags < br >John Doe< /b > before adding contact in to MutliAutoCompliteTextView. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read about Spanned/Spannable interface

Comment: Are you using a `Filter` on your adapter?